# A float is supposed to be signed, so why is subtraction causing a wrap-around?

Tags: objective-c, types, type-conversion

```
float test=-1;
```

produces a `float` with value `-1`. However,

```
float test=arc4random()%500-500;
```

produces enormous values that clearly resulted from a buffer overflow -- the numbers wrapping around. This should not happen with a `float`; for kicks, I tried to see if Xcode would let me make a "signed float", but it told me "floats cannot be signed or unsigned."

I produced a work-around where I made a signed `int`, then cast it to a `float`, but I'd really appreciate knowing how/why this happened.

Comment: The fact that you assign the result to a `float` has no effect on how the result is calculated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`arc4random()` returns a `u_int32_t` according to the man page, so `arc4random()%500-500` will be an unsigned integer, and subtracting 500 will give you a very large positive value. Try this instead:

```
float test = ((float)(arc4random() % 500))-500;
```

> I produced a work-around where I made a signed int, then cast it to a
>   float, but I'd really appreciate knowing how/why this happened.

Look at the entire line one piece at a time. First, you've got:

```
arc4random()
```

As I said above, that returns an unsigned int. Let's pretend that it returns the value `12345`. Next, you've got the modulus operator, so your expression is something like:

```
12345 % 500
```

which is to say `345`. Next, you subtract 500:

```
345 - 500
```

You'd think that'd give you -155, but no -- we're still working in the realm of unsigned ints here, so you really get `4294967141` (or something like that -- my math may be off). Then, finally, you assign that to a float:

```
float test = 4294967141;
```

A float only has 23 bits for the mantissa, so the value that's stored in `test` will be in the general neighborhood of 4294967141, but with less precision, like 4294970000.

Comment: wouldnt the `%500` reduce the output down to 0-499?

Comment: @DanF Yes, exactly. And then you subtract 500, giving a value somewhere south of 0. But since `arc4random()` returns an unsigned value, the entire expression will be unsigned. It only becomes a `float` when it's assigned to `test`.

Comment: Ah, I see the problem then, I didn't know it treated the entire expression as unsigned

Comment: Thanks! Will cast to float as you said above. What's weird though is that I got it to work with:
`signed int testsi = arc4random()%500-500;` `float test=(float)testsi;`
I assume it made the unsigned int, then when casting to a signed int, it fixed the problem, so the cast to float worked properly, though that was a pretty messy way of doing things.

Answer (score 0):

floats in Objective-C are exactly the same as they are in C: inherently signed as defined by IEEE-754. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_precision_floating-point_format